# Keeping only one decimal in string

Tags: java, string

I want to save only numbers and a single decimal from string, but did not find any case where only one decimal can be stored. The codes i saw was similar to this

```
String str="12.2.3.4";
String a=str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

What can i do to keep only one decimal and remove other.I want to get output in this form

```
12.234
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to do it with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("12.2.3.4");

int firstPosition = sb.indexOf(".");

for ( int lastPosition = sb.lastIndexOf(".");
      lastPosition > firstPosition;
      lastPosition = sb.lastIndexOf(".", lastPosition ) ) {
    sb.deleteCharAt(lastPosition);
}

String result = sb.toString();
```

This basically looks for all `.` occurrences starting from the right and going to the left, as long as they are not the first `.`, and deletes each of them.

If there is only one decimal or none at all, the loop condition will be false from the start so no changes will be made.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBulder();
String[] as = str.split("\\.");
sb.append(as[0]);
if(as.length > 1) {
  sb.append(".");
}
for(int i = 1; i < as.length; i ++) {
  sb.append(as[i]);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the old fashioned way

```
public String formatOneDecimalPoint(String str) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  boolean foundPoint = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != '.') {
      sb.append(str.charAt(i));
    } else if (!foundPoint) {
      sb.append(str.charAt(i));
      foundPoint = true;
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way using [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

```
public class OneDecimalString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = "12.2.3.4";
        String a[] = str.split("\\.");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sb.append(a[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                sb.append(".");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Output: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```